# How to run an aggregate, bitwise XOR (bit_xor) function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#bit_xor), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_bit-xor), [Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/aggregate_functions?hl=da#bit_xor), and [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/bit-xor-function.html) provide a `bit_xor` aggregate function, which can run a bitwise XOR operation on all 64-bit integers in a group (from a `GROUP BY` query).

How would I run an aggregate bitwise XOR in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Maybe this can be done with a custom aggregate function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes, you could write a custom aggregate. A cursor would also work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981050/aggregate-bitwise-or-in-a-subquery

Comment: You could mask off the bits into 64 columns, count them up, and test for odd or even.

Answer (score 0):

The **^** bitwise operator in SQL Server performs a bitwise logical exclusive OR between the two expressions, taking each corresponding bit for both expressions.

Example:

```
SELECT a_int_value ^ b_int_value  
FROM bitwise;  
GO
```

For aggregate bitwise xor SQL Server does not have native support but you can create a function as below:

[SQL Server : bitwise operation in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902765/sql-server-bitwise-operation-in-group-by)

Comment: Yes, but what about across all values in a group (aggregate)? Can this be used with a custom aggregate?

Comment: I changed the response

Comment: Did you try it?